C# : EPPlus calculation is different from Excel
I use C# and EPPlus (v7.1.3) to do some Excel operations. But I found that EPPlus calculations are different from the result displayed by Excel.

The cell A1 is
=RIGHT(DEC2HEX((B1 * 256 / 6.25 / 4), 4), 2)

Cell B1 is 3. The result will show 1E in cell A1.
But when I use EPPlus to calculate this, it returns a result of 1F.
Thanks
Here's my code:
ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage( filename );
ExcelCalculationOption option = new ExcelCalculationOption();
option.PrecisionAndRoundingStrategy = PrecisionAndRoundingStrategy.DotNet;
ep.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"].Calculate( option );
Console.WriteLine( ep.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"].Value );

option.PrecisionAndRoundingStrategy = PrecisionAndRoundingStrategy.Excel;
ep.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"].Calculate( option );
Console.WriteLine( ep.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"].Value );

The console output:
1F  
1F

I expect at least one of them should be 1E.

It's look like rounding problem. Try to use the INT function first:   =RIGHT(DEC2HEX((INT(B1*256/6.25/4)),4),2)

Thanks. Yes, you're right. but this makes formula uncertanty. I can't know whether my formula would cause different value or not.

Here provides a workaround when someone like me can't leave epplus and need calculate right formula result.
I use epplus and Excel.Interop the same time.
step 1. use epplus to do your job and save file
step 2. use Excel.Interop load file
step 3. re-calculate worksheet and save file
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open( filename );
workbook.ForceFullCalculation = true;

foreach( Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Worksheets ) {
  Excel.Range targetRange = (Excel.Range)ws.UsedRange;
  targetRange.Copy( Type.Missing );
  targetRange.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
  Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false );
}
workbook.Close( true );
excelApp.Quit();

After that.
When epplus load file againg. it can read the right value.
I know this is stupid but ..... it's a workaround for me.
